# Visible overflow hiding overlapping element

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am attempting to use the `overflow: visible;` property in order to show a child element passing the parent element. My attempt is failing and the child element (the image) is getting cut off at the top of the parent element.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```css
#blue {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
} 
#redBanner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 background: #b22525;
 position: relative;
 overflow: visible;
}
#redBannerImg {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 10%;
 width: 40%;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="blue">
</section>
<section id="redBanner">
  <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/07/22/2057921811589a1.jpg" alt="" id="redBannerImg">
</section>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The image extends above the red box.

Comment: @showdev In firefox I cannot see the top part of the image. I undestood that's what OP wants.

Comment: @raul.vila Is that because the red box is right up against the top of the window? If I move the red box down, the image extends above it. [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/5z6zpm19/).

Comment: @showdev yes, that's another way to fix the problem. Not sure what OP really wants.

Comment: I guess my issue is I have this up against another ending `</section>` tag. What should I do with this in mind?

Comment: It might help to describe the layout you're trying to achieve. Maybe `overflow:visible` is not the most effective solution.

Comment: I just figured it out. I forgot that the section above this one had a `z-index` applied. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `top: 0;`instead of `bottom: 0;` it works, but not sure if that brokes your design.

```css
#redBanner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 background: #b22525;
 position: relative;
 overflow: visible;
}
#redBannerImg {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 10%;
 width: 40%;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="redBanner">
  <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/07/22/2057921811589a1.jpg" alt="" id="redBannerImg">
</section>
```